# delete node from linked list (C++)

Tags: c++

I don't understand how this code can delete node, please help!!!

```
 Node* del_place(Node* L, int S)
{

        int i=1;
        Node *p=L;
        while (p!=NULL&&i!=S-1)
        {
            p=p->next;
            i++;
        }
        p->next=p->next->next;//why can this code delete node in L...
              return L;
      }
```

Comment: This is a random code snippet. Please post a [mcve] and explain *what* you don't understand.

Comment: You should go through the function line by line, and think about what each line does. Pay particular attention to where each pointer points to.

Comment: Bring out paper and a pen(cil), draw a linked list, and see what happens when you draw `p->next=p->next->next;`.

Comment: And it does not really delete it as much as loose it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at what the function does. It takes two arguments, the linked list, and the index of the item to be removed.

First, it searches the right node:
p is the first item of the linked list. It starts stepping through the list, untill either, the right index is found (`i=S-1`) or untill the end of the list is reached (`p=NULL`).

when it has found the right node, it sets the link to the next item: `p-> next`, to the next item of the next item.

And now, you can also see the problems in the function:

- When an item is removed, the item itself is still in the list, there
  is just no more pointer to it, this is a memory leak like molbdnilo said.
- When the end of the list is reached (p=NULL), you try to set p->next to NULL, this will cause the program to throw a nullpointerexception.
- If p itself is the last item in the list, p->Next will be null, and since you try to call 'Next' on this item, you will also get a nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 1):

The line does not actually delete the `Node` from the memory. It removes it from the linked list.

The code makes your current `Node` (`p`) points to the second `Node` on the right instead of the first on the right.

Several issues with this code:

- Potential memory leak since the `Node` is not deleted from the memory
- you need to do some check before `p->next=p->next->next;` or you might have some undefined behaviour when `p` or `p->next` end up being `NULL`. e.g. `L` is NULL, `S` > size of the linked list...